# What is the term for a language that is a second language for most people?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

What is the term for a language that is a second language for most of the people that use it? For example, when the Portuguese traded with East African countries in the 1700's, none of them spoke their mother tongue. English can also been seen as this type of language. It is two words and sounds Latin.

Comment: You're probably thinking of [*lingua franca*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lingua_franca), which designates a language which is no one's native language but employed for communication between speakers of different languages.

Comment: The answer is of course **klingon**. It probably has the fewest native speakers.

Comment: This was a crossword type of question? Amazingly, although users have mentioned  it in various answers in the past, I could not find any question that had "lingua franca" as its answer.

Answer (score 19):

lingua franca

[From the Merriam Webster dictionary](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/lingua%20franca):

> **lin·gua fran·ca** \ˈliŋ-gwə-ˈfraŋ-kə\
>
> noun
>
> : a language that is used among people who speak various different languages
>
> *Full Definition*
>
> 1. often capitalized : a common language consisting of Italian mixed with French, Spanish, Greek, and Arabic that was formerly spoken in Mediterranean ports
> 2. : any of various languages used as common or commercial tongues among peoples of diverse speech
> 3. : something resembling a common language
>
> Plural: **lingua francas** or **lin·guae fran·cae** -gwē-ˈfraŋ-(ˌ)kē\
>
> *Examples*
>
> English is used as a lingua franca among many airline pilots.
>
> *Origin*: Italian, literally, Frankish language.
>
> First use: 1619

Comment: Please provide a link to the original page or answer; Quote only the relevant portion; Provide the name of the original author, wherever possible."

Comment: Funny, I always thought the "original" lingua franca was French, but it was Italian!

Comment: @JoeBlow Nah, but the French gave us something similar.  We call it the metric system.

Comment: @JoeBlow According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frankish_language): Frankish (also Old Franconian) was the West Germanic language spoken by the Franks between the 4th and 8th century. The language itself is poorly attested, but it gave rise to numerous loanwords in Old French. [The Franks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Franks) "... are historically first known as a group of Germanic tribes that inhabited the land between the Lower and Middle Rhine in the 3rd century AD, and second as the people of Gaul who merged with the Gallo-Roman populations during succeeding centuries ..."

Comment: ... so the original *Lingua Franca* was Frankish (which evolved into Old French), not Italian. The phrase "Lingua Franca", as I understand it, is Italian.

Comment: Ah. That makes more sense @AgiHammerthief.  **Great explanation, thanks.**  You mean around like Bonn / the Mosel ??

Comment: I am not familiar with the geography of that part of the world, but looking at Wikipedia's description of that area, I am inclined to reply "yes, around there".

Comment: @AgiHammerthief: [EO](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?search=lingua+franca) tells that the "franca" part of "lingua franca" is actually from an Arabic custom, common at the time (and dating back to the crusades), of referring to all Europeans as Franks, even though the specific "lingua franca" referred to had nothing to do with Frankish.

Comment: @Dolda2000 You could probably post your comment as an answer if you expanded it a little. The reason I understood "franca" to mean "Frankish" is from this line in the answer: "*Origin*: Italian, literally, Frankish language", Frankish being specific the the Rhine area and ancient France, as indicated by my previous comments.

Comment: I'm not sure whether getting reputation points for this answer counts as gaming the system. I got the answer from my mom before I saw StoneyB's comment.